# Grub not starting on recently Debian install

Tags: debian, boot, windows, grub

i recently install Debian 7.4.0 on my laptop.

The problem is when i reboot my system it start on Windows 7 by default, i tried to boot again the Debian installer and my surprise was the boot USB load the grub screen, with the option to load Debian and Windows 7. But if i try without the USB it starts on Windows 7.

What could i do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what you tell it seems like you have installed GRUB to your USB-device that you installed from. This is why the installer does not boot when you boot from your USB-device.

Resolve it by booting into Debian with the USB-device, then remove it once you have booted.

Login to the Debian installation and run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

where X is the device file representing the hard drive where Debian was installed.

If you only have one hard drive it should be /dev/sda, you can use the command lsblk to list all block devices.

Comment: Thanks i installed it again from debian and it works! :D. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/restore-debian-linux-grub-boot-loader.html) and don't forget run os-prober if you want to use Windows.